# Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function

Tags: pine-script

The script below does not compile.
It throws the error `Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function`
I don't understand why.
The arguments I use in the security function are not mutable variables.
When I comment out the line `h := h * 3`, the script compiles ok.
Does anybody know what's going on here?
Could this be a Pine script bug?

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

[h, l, c] = security(syminfo.ticker, "D", [high,low,close], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on) // actual daily high,low,close.
h := h * 3 // Commenting this line results removes the error: "Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function."

plot(h)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, destructured assignments aren't treated the same way when a user-defined function returns them vs when `security()` does. Encapsulating your `security()` call in a function will work:

```
//@version=4
study("")
f_sec() => security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [high,low,close], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
[h, l, c] = f_sec()
h := h * 3
plot(h)
```

Note that you are using future data on historical bars when using lookahead and not offsetting the series by 1, as you are doing in there.

Comment: I'm aware that I'm using future data because I need to know the high/low on the first bar. Not sure what you mean by offseting the series by 1. I'm not doing that as far as I can see.